# Accessing and Enable/disable UIViewalert Button in ios 7 and earlier

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, uialertview

I am stuck on Accessing uialertview buttons in ios 7 . when googling i read ios 7 did not allow to customize or chenging the uialert view button .

I want to do these functionality in my project my deployment target is 5.0-

->I want to disable AlertView first button disable for 15 second with its title like this 
OK(15),OK(14)......OK(0),OK(with user enable). After completion 15 seconds user can tap to the ok button to dismiss the alert view .

please suggest me how to do this.

Can i get the ok (fist button) of alert view and can change its title as i write above .

Or 
 i have to use custom alert view .

I want to show the default looking UIAlert which match with IOS 7 and earlier version Ui

Thanks .

Comment: check the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol reference page. start the countdown and when it finishes send a clickedButtonAtIndex message. until you send it, the button stays inactive.

Comment: @Marius i also want to change the title of button in every timer call back .

Comment: please upvote my previous comment if it answered your question. I can also move the comment and make it an Answer.